# Cannot understand friend functions in a template class

Tags: c++, templates, friend

This is code i have written to understand the concept. The code is fine and it runs.

What i dont understand is that why is the marked line needed ?

```
template <class T>
class D
{
    public :
    template <class P>  //<------------------Why is this needed ? --------------
    friend void print(D <P> obj);
};

template <class T>
void print(D<T> obj)
{std::cout<<sizeof(T);};


int main()
{
    D <char>obj3;
    print(obj3);
    return 0;
}
```

or in other words why does the following not run ?

```
template <class T>
class D
{
    public :
    friend void print(D <T> obj);
};
```

Comment: That line shows that `print()` is itself a `template` function.

Comment: Why is that needed in the class ? The template function has a complete definition outside the class, plus instantiation is done with knowledge of the data type ..

Comment: As per the syntax of template function before declaring template function you must write it like this...                        `template <class P>
    friend void print(D <P> obj);` I think that must be a reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per [temp.friend], you must provide explicit template arguments to make a specialisation of a template function a friend:

```
template <class T>
class D
{
    public :
    friend void print<T>(D <T> obj);
};
```

Without it, the compiler will be looking for a function `print()`, not a function template `print()`.

Comment: Could you explain what are explicit template arguments ? Cant really get a hang of it from the sites that google is turning up ..

Comment: @AshRj I'll explain on calls as there it's easiest, but it applies to all times you're referring to a function template. Let's assume you have an instance defined `D<int> d;`. When calling `print()`, you can either provide the tempalte arguments explicitly: `print<int>(d);`, or do not provide them and let the compiler deduce them from the context (here, from the argument): `print(d);`. Providing them explicitly means listing them in angle brackets `< >`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I got what you are saying but i still cant get how that explains your answer .. Could you direct me to anyplace where i can read about how templates work ? I think the main issue here is that i dont understand how templates are handled by the compiler, hence, the difficulty in understanding something so simple ..

Comment: @AshRj In my answer, the explicit argument is the `<T>` in `print<T>(`. I don't know a reference I could suggest, but there's a list of [books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) here on SO, perhaps you can work your way from there. [temp.friend] in my answer is a reference to the C++11 ISO standard.